# Xamarin.Android project with reference to PCL Visual Basic .NET

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, portable-class-library

I use visual studio 2013. In my solution I have two projects, a Portal Class Libray in Visual Basic Language, and Xamarin.Android Project.

Xamarin.Android project has a reference to the PCL visual basic. 
So far everything works fine, but when I go to Xamarin.Android compile or debug the application on a phone or emulator, throws me the following error:

Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll'
   en Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() App.Androidx

As I can fix this? And I searched the help of Xamarin here:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/portable_visual_basic_net/

but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20005217/254041 to a similiar question.