# VB.NET DLL not possible in a Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: vb.net, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to reference a VB.NET DLL in a Xamarin.Forms (Portable) application.  During the course of my research, I found the following post that might allow this:  [Xamarin.Android and VB.Net Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768151/xamarin-android-and-vb-net-libaries/20005217#20005217)

I've tried to use the "Embed" work-around mentioned in the link, but the Xamarin.Forms project would fail to build because it can't load the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly, version 8.0.0.0.

I've also found the following link as well during my research that should allow at least some VB.NET usage in a Xamarin application:  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/portable_visual_basic_net/xamarin-forms/

At the bottom of the site, there is a "Limitations of VB.NET in Xamarin.Forms" section.  With the last item:  "Xamarin does not support the Visual Basic.NET language," does that simply mean that you can't use a VB.NET dll in any Xamarin.Forms (portable) project that happens to also reference Xamarin.Forms.Core, Xamarin.Forms.Platform, and Xamarin.Forms.Xaml?

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

A DLL doesn't contain it's dependencies. If your DLL relies on `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, you will need to load the DLL that contains that assembly as well.

So either remove the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly reference from the VB DLL, or include it as a reference in your Xamarin project (which may or may not be possible, I am not sure.)